# Configure port 1935 in iptables for media

Tags: iptables, media

On CentOs 6.4 I cannot connect to the media server from port 1935 only 5080. I have read you can edit the `iptables` files with following.

1. Open flle /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

   ```
   $ sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
   ```
2. Append rule as follows:

   ```
   -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport XY -j    ACCEPT
   ```
3. Save and close the file. Restart iptables:

   ```
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables restart
   ```

How would I specifically configure port 1935? The above seems to be open to all ports, is this correct? Do I replace XY with 1935?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just opens port `XY`, i.e., there you should put your 1935.

I'd advise to use the command your distribution uses to configure the firewall (on Fedora, RHEL and clones it is `system-config-firewall`). Easier on the brain, less likely to screw everything up, takes care of ancilliary tasks like reloading rules and saving them away for later boots).

Comment: The above script is for CentOs 6.4 so it will be alright? Or are you saying generally configure the firewall.